# How to get Customer attribute value by loading customer id in magento 2

Tags: customer, grid, backend, magento2.3, customer-attribute

I have customer entity id, how do i get customer attribute value by loading customer entity id, Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**you can use this code to get customer attribute value.**

```
class MyClass 
    {
        protected $_customer;
        protected $_customerFactory;

        public function __construct(...
               \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
               \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
        )
        {
            ...
            $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
            $this->_customer = $customers;
        }

        public function getCustomerCollection() {
            return $this->_customer->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                   ->load();
        }

        public function getFilteredCustomerCollection() {
            return $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                    ->addAttributeToFilter("firstname", array("eq" => "Max"))
                    -load();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends where you want that information, template, some module etc. you can use below code to get customer object data :

```
$id = xxx; // customer id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
        ->load($id);
$customerFirstName = $customerObj->getFirstName();
```